# Vaadin java.lang.NullPointerException: bean cannot be null (binder)

Tags: vaadin

I consistantly get the Exception `NullPointerException: bean cannot be null`.
I use a service and have a mongoDB locally. I can get the information from it. But if i want to push the button for add my inputs i get this NullPointerException.
My pom is also referring to the latest versions of my dependencies.

How can I avoid this Exception?

````
   @Route(value = "adddevice", layout = MainLayout.class)
   @RolesAllowed({"ADMIN", "USER"})
  public class NewDeviceView extends VerticalLayout {

  NewDeviceForm form;
  DeviceService service;

  public NewDeviceView(DeviceService service){
      this.service=service;

      form = new NewDeviceForm();
      form.addListener(NewDeviceForm.SaveEvent.class, this::saveDevice);

      configureForm();
      add(getContent());
  }

  private HorizontalLayout getContent() {
      HorizontalLayout content = new HorizontalLayout(form);
      content.setFlexGrow(2);
      content.setFlexGrow(1, form);
      content.addClassNames("content");
      content.setSizeFull();
      return content;
  }

  private void configureForm() {
      form = new NewDeviceForm();
      form.addListener(NewDeviceForm.SaveEvent.class, this::saveDevice);
  }

  private void saveDevice(NewDeviceForm.SaveEvent event) {
      service.saveDevice(event.getDevice());
  }

} ```


  ```public class NewDeviceForm extends FormLayout {

  private Device device;

  TextField alias = new TextField("Alias Hinzufügen");
  TextField aetit = new TextField("AET Hinzufügen");
  TextField ipAdress = new TextField("IPAdress Hinzufügen");
  TextField port = new TextField("Port Hinzufügen");
  TextField incomingDirectory = new TextField("Eingangsverzeichnis Hinzufügen");

  Binder<Device> binder = new BeanValidationBinder<>(Device.class);

  Button addButton = new Button("Hinzufügen");
  Button backButton = new Button("Back");



  public NewDeviceForm(){

      binder.bindInstanceFields(this);

      add(
              alias,
              aetit,
              ipAdress,
              port,
              incomingDirectory,
              createButtonsLayout()
      );
  }

  private Component createButtonsLayout() {
      addButton.addClickShortcut(Key.ENTER);
      addButton.addClickListener(event -> validateAndSave());

      binder.addStatusChangeListener(e -> addButton.setEnabled(binder.isValid()));

      return new HorizontalLayout(addButton,backButton);
  }

  public void validateAndSave(){
      try {
          binder.writeBean(device);
          fireEvent(new SaveEvent(this, device));
      } catch (ValidationException e){
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }

  public void setDevice(Device device){
      this.device = device;
      binder.readBean(device);
  }

  public static abstract class NewDeviceFormEvent extends ComponentEvent<NewDeviceForm> {
      private Device device;

      protected NewDeviceFormEvent(NewDeviceForm source, Device device){
          super(source,false);
          this.device=device;
      }

      public Device getDevice(){
          return device;
      }
  }

  public static class SaveEvent extends NewDeviceFormEvent {
      SaveEvent(NewDeviceForm source, Device device){
          super(source,device);
      }
  }

  public <T extends ComponentEvent<?>> Registration addListener(
          Class<T> eventType, ComponentEventListener<T> listener){
      return getEventBus().addListener(eventType, listener);
  }

}```



java.lang.NullPointerException: bean cannot be null
  at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:233) ~[na:na]
  at com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.Binder.doWriteIfValid(Binder.java:2280) ~[flow-data-23.1.3.jar:23.1.3]
  at com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.Binder.writeBean(Binder.java:2194) ~[flow-data-23.1.3.jar:23.1.3]
  at com.example.application.form.NewDeviceForm.validateAndSave(NewDeviceForm.java:59) ~[classes/:na]
  at com.example.application.form.NewDeviceForm.lambda$createButtonsLayout$b71f5360$1(NewDeviceForm.java:50) ~[classes/:na]
  at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.fireEventForListener(ComponentEventBus.java:206) ~[flow-server-23.1.3.jar:23.1.3]
  at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.handleDomEvent(ComponentEventBus.java:448) ~[flow-server-23.1.3.jar:23.1.3]
  at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.lambda$addDomTrigger$dd1b7957$1(ComponentEventBus.java:265) ~[flow-server-23.1.3.jar:23.1.3]
  at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.ElementListenerMap.lambda$fireEvent$2(ElementListenerMap.java:447) ~[flow-server-23.1.3.jar:23.1.3]
  at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
  at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.ElementListenerMap.fireEvent(ElementListenerMap.java:447) ~[flow-server-23.1.3.jar:23.1.3]
  at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.EventRpcHandler.handleNode(EventRpcHandler.java:62) ~[flow-server-23.1.3.jar:23.1.3]
  at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.AbstractRpcInvocationHandler.handle(AbstractRpcInvocationHandler.java:75) ~[flow-server-23.1.3.jar:23.1.3]
  at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocationData(ServerRpcHandler.java:438) ~[flow-server-23.1.3.jar:23.1.3]
  at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.lambda$handleInvocations$1(ServerRpcHandler.java:419) ~[flow-server-23.1.3.jar:23.1.3]
  at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
  at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:419) ~[flow-server-23.1.3.jar:23.1.3]
  at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:320) ~[flow-server-23.1.3.jar:23.1.3]
  at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:115) ~[flow-server-23.1.3.jar:23.1.3]
  at com.vaadin.flow.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40) ~[flow-server-23.1.3.jar:23.1.3]
  at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1564) ~[flow-server-23.1.3.jar:23.1.3]
  at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:299) ~[flow-server-23.1.3.jar:23.1.3]
  at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringServlet.service(SpringServlet.java:109) ~[vaadin-spring-23.1.3.jar:na]
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:4.0.FR]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:711) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:353) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:313) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:141) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:51) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:4.0.FR]
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:4.0.FR]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
  at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
  at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
  at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
  at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
  at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
  at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
  at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
  at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
  at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:223) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
  at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
  at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
  at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
  at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
  at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
  at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
  at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1787) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
````

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. The device in validateAndSave is null. Have you debugged your code?

Comment: Yes, and was null. But i am blind and don't understand why is it so.

Comment: I don't see it either. Can you share your code?

Comment: Is it possible in your form to attempt saving it before you have even populated the form? As you see device is is set in setDevice method. So if save button is enabled by default, you can click it and save when device == null. Try the following. Make the save button disabled by default and enable it in setDevice. What happens?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anywhere that you actually call setDevice().  And why is setDevice() outside the class that contains getDevice()?